# getting percent CSS position with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to get an element's CSS (top and left) with jQuery:

```
$(element).css('top');
```

but instead of "12%" like it should be, I get the pixels. 
How do I get the percent?

HTML:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.parWrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top: 40%
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div> 
    <div id="crap" class="parWrapper" style="left:50%">
    Wrap1   
    </div>

    <div class="parWrapper">
    Wrap2
    </div>

    <div class="parWrapper">
    Wrap3   
    </div>

    <div class="parWrapper">
    Wrap4   
    </div>

    <div class="parWrapper">
    Wrap5   
    </div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you show your html and css for the element? In the following example I am getting the % http://jsfiddle.net/Nalum/yMTVv/ though I have only tested this in Google Chrome. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 17):

I just encountered this myself and thought it weird, too.

Instead of:

```
 $(element).css('top');
```

I just did:

```
 element.style.top
```

No jQuery and gives you the actual value in the type you made it (percent, ems, etc.)

Comment: This is definitely more useful than taking the height of the parent and then reverse-engineering it to calculate the percentage.

Answer (score 15):

You can do this:

```
$(element).position().top / $(element).parent().height() * 100
```

Regarding your precedent comment, if you want to work with css('top'), don't forget to parseInt it.

Comment: as i mentioned before, height of parent returns 0

Comment: parent's height becomes 0 if you use float or a position:[absolute|fixed] on it.

Comment: -1: Getting the actual value instead of calculating it would be better practice. - `element.style.top`

Comment: oh 3 years past my answer, still getting comments :D. Actually OP asked for a way to get a percentage with jQuery. I replied by saying to calculate it (so that you're 100% sure to get a percentage). But I agree that if you need to get the value directly from the styles `element.style.top` is a better way ;)

Answer (score 10):

This is also an option:

```
$(element)[0].style.top
```

Answer (score 1):

calculate it by your own:

```
($(element).css('top') / parentHeight) * 100;
```

Comment: not working, ($(element).css('top').substr(0,$(theobj).css('top').length-2) / $(element).parent().height()) * 100; gives me NaN (height of parent is 0)

Comment: what about parseInt($(element).css('top'))

Answer (score 1):

I had a need to calculate something similiar but in my case it was the left %, you can update the code below to use the window height if you are going for a vertical percentage value -

```
getLeftPercent = function() {
    var leftStr = $('#my-obj').css('left'),
        pxPos = leftStr.indexOf('px'),
        leftVal = leftStr.substr(0, pxPos),
        leftPercent = (leftVal / $(window).width() * 100).toString(),
        dotPos = leftPercent.indexOf('.'),
        leftPercentStr = dotPos == -1 ? leftPercent + '%' : leftPercent.substr(0, dotPos) + '%';
    return leftPercentStr;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a (very easy) way to do this!
Even when using stylesheets.
**The key is to prevent jquery from calculating the value by temporarily hiding the parent.**

```
$(element).parent().hide();
var top = $(element).css("top");
$(element).parent().show();
console.log(top);
```

voila!

If you want just the number without the "%" use

```
top = parseFloat(top);
```

BTW: Don't worry, the hiding and reshowing is so quick, it won't be visible for your users.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. You can change the "element" and "parent" to be compatible with your project.

```
var parent_height = $(element).parent().height(); // Height of parent. If you do something related to "width", get parent's width.

var top_val_px   = $(element).css('top');
var top_val_only = top_val_px.slice(0,-2); // Remove "px" part
var top_Percentage = (top_val_only/parent_height) * 100; // Percentage will be a close value.
```

I used a similar code and it worked.