# jQuery IF not working with position relative + percentage values

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I'm really struggling on this one.

I'm trying to create a menu that slides left and right to hide itself, with jquery.

I need to make it `left: 100%` and, on clicking the toggle, make it `left: 0`

To do so, I also need it to be `position relative`. But it seems that, if it has `position relative`, the jquery `if` doesn't work.

```
$('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
        if ( $('.menu').css('left') == '100%' ) {
            alert('left 100%');
            $(this).text('keyboard_arrow_right');
            $('.menu').stop().animate({
                left: 0
            }, 500);
        }
        else {
            alert('left not 100%');
            $(this).text('menu');
            $('.menu').stop().animate({
                left: '100%'
            }, 500);
        }
});
```

I made this fiddle to make it easier to test: https://jsfiddle.net/z2cjLrtq/2/

If you try and remove the `position relative` from the fiddle, the code works BUT, then, `left: 100%` won't do a thing since it doesn't have the `position relative`

I also tried using `px` instead of `%` and it works as well! But that won't do me any good either since it will be a dynamic menu with fluid width.

I'm starting to think this is a jquery bug...

Is there any solution to this?

I would really appreciate some help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting percent CSS position with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230425/getting-percent-css-position-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.menu').css('left')` returns the actual (calculated) value in pixels, e.g. `0px` or `879px`, and not `100%`.

Therefore all you have to do is reverse your logic, so that you check for the `0px` case (when the menu is at the left) instead of trying to work out which pixel value is equivalent to `100%`. Something like this:

```
$('.menu-toggle').click(function(){

        if ( $('.menu').css('left') == '0px' ) {
            $(this).text('menu');
            $('.menu').stop().animate({
                left: '100%'
            }, 500);
        }
        else {
            alert($('.menu').css('left'));
            $(this).text('keyboard_arrow_right');
            $('.menu').stop().animate({
                left: 0
            }, 500);
        }
});
```

Comment: I didn't know about that one. My headache is gone. You're a live savior!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to add a class when it's hidden, as I did in following jsfiddle. An advantage of this is that you can always get the state of your menu (hidden or not), simply by checking if it has the class.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z2cjLrtq/6/)

```
    $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
        if ( $('.menu').hasClass("hiddenRight")) {
            alert('left 100%');
            $(this).text('keyboard_arrow_right');
            $('.menu').stop().animate({
                left: 0
            }, 500);
            $('.menu').removeClass("hiddenRight");
        }
        else {
            alert('left not 100%');
            $(this).text('menu');
            $('.menu').stop().animate({
                left: '100%'
            }, 500);
            $('.menu').addClass("hiddenRight");
        }
    });
```